# Is there a better way than stacked if else

Tags: templating, matrix, forloop

i am using a slider in my template, and depending on if the user filled out values in the craft matrix (slides can have up to 4 rows) i want to have twig compile only the necessary code. I am not sure if my attempt is way too long and it could be archived much easier. thanks a lot for the help

```
  <div id="slider-with-blocks-1" class="royalSlider rsMinW">
    {% for block in entry.slideitemtop %}
    {% set Bild = block.ImageSlideTop.first() %}
    {% if block.textCSlideTop is empty and block.textBSlideTop is empty and block.textASlideTop is empty and block.headlineSlideTop is empty %}
    <div class="rsContent slide3">
      <a class="rsImg" href="{{ Bild.url }}"></a>
    </div>
    {% elseif block.textCSlideTop is empty and block.textBSlideTop is empty and block.textASlideTop is empty %}
    <div class="rsContent slide3">
      <a class="rsImg" href="{{ Bild.url }}"></a>
      <div class="bContainer">
        <strong data-move-effect="none" class="rsABlock txtCent blockSubHeadline">{{ block.headlineSlideTop }}</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% elseif block.textCSlideTop is empty and block.textBSlideTop is empty %}
    <div class="rsContent slide4">
      <a class="rsImg" href="{{ Bild.url }}"></a>
      <div class="bContainer">
        <strong data-move-effect="none" class="rsABlock txtCent blockSubHeadline">{{ block.headlineSlideTop }}</strong>
        <span data-move-effect="top" class="rsABlock txtCent">{{ block.textASlideTop }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% elseif block.textCSlideTop is empty %}
    <div class="rsContent slide1">
      <a class="rsImg" href="{{ Bild.url }}"></a>
      <div class="bContainer">
        <strong data-move-effect="none" class="rsABlock txtCent blockSubHeadline">{{ block.headlineSlideTop }}</strong>
        <span data-move-effect="top" class="rsABlock txtCent">{{ block.textASlideTop }}</span>
        <span data-move-effect="bottom" class="rsABlock txtCent">{{ block.textBSlideTop }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="rsContent slide1">
      <a class="rsImg" href="{{ Bild.url }}"></a>
      <div class="bContainer">
        <strong data-move-effect="none" class="rsABlock txtCent blockSubHeadline">{{ block.headlineSlideTop }}</strong>
        <span data-move-effect="top" class="rsABlock txtCent">{{ block.textASlideTop }}</span>
        <span data-move-effect="bottom" class="rsABlock txtCent">{{ block.textBSlideTop }}</span>
        <span data-move-effect="left" class="rsABlock txtCent">{{ block.textCSlideTop }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is certainly a lot of repeated code here so we can definitely improve on that! There are so many ways you could handle your Twig templates but this is how I would do it:

```
<div id="slider-with-blocks-1" class="royalSlider rsMinW">
    {% for block in entry.slideitemtop %}
        {% set Bild = block.ImageSlideTop.first() %}

        <div class="rsContent slide{{ loop.index }}">
            <a class="rsImg" href="{{ Bild.url }}"></a>
            <div class="bContainer">
                {% if block.headlineSlideTop|length %}
                    <strong data-move-effect="none" class="rsABlock txtCent blockSubHeadline">{{ block.headlineSlideTop }}</strong>
                {% endif %}
                {% if block.textASlideTop|length %}
                    <span data-move-effect="top" class="rsABlock txtCent">{{ block.textASlideTop }}</span>
                {% endif %}
                {% if block.textBSlideTop|length %}
                    <span data-move-effect="bottom" class="rsABlock txtCent">{{ block.textBSlideTop }}</span>
                {% endif %}
                {% if block.textCSlideTop|length %}
                    <span data-move-effect="left" class="rsABlock txtCent">{{ block.textCSlideTop }}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

All we are doing here is using the same template code for each slide, but for each loop through we are checking if the 4 fields have any content or not.

I also noticed a `slide1` class. You can also automatically increment the number at the end of the class for each loop using `{{ loop.index }}`.